# Probability of z more outcomes in one category than another in a multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution

If I have a multinomial distribution $X_1, ..., X_n$ from $m$ trials with probabilities $p_1, ... p_n$, what is the probability that there are $z$ more outcomes $X_1$ than $X_2$ (i.e. $\Pr(X_1 - X_2  = z)$)?

Obviously, I could do this with a sum, $\sum_{j=z}^{floor((n+z)/2)} \frac{n!}{j! (j-z)! (n - 2j + z)!} p_1^k p_2^{j-z} (1 - p_1 - p_2)^{n - 2j + z}$, but this is extremely difficult to use and do inference with. Is there another, simpler answer?

Comment: Do you not have access to a function that calculates multinomial probabilities, which naturally would reduce this to a nested loop with a sum of function return values in the inner step - about 4 lines of code, including initializing the sum to zero?

Comment: I do, but I'd also like to be able to derive some analytic results if possible.